# BigQueryHook operator not recognizing use_legacy_sql argument

Tags: airflow, google-cloud-composer

Trying to run a query using pythonoperator (using BigQueryHook)

```
def CheckIncomingRecords(**context):
    sql = context['templates_dict']['sql']
    logging.info("sql passed is : {}".format(sql))
    bq = BigQueryHook(bigquery_conn_id='bigquery_default', 
use_legacy_sql=False)
    conn = bq.get_conn()
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    results = cursor.execute(sql)
return results
```

Getting the below error:

TypeError: **init**() got an unexpected keyword argument 'use_legacy_sql'

Using 1.9.0-composer. Checked the source code and can't find out why its not recognizing the argument mentioned in the doc.

Comment: Are you using Python 2 or Python 3 in your environment?

Answer (score 2):

The error you are getting is because in **Airflow 1.9.0** only 2 parameters exist in BigQueryHook:

Source code: https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/1.9.0/airflow/contrib/hooks/bigquery_hook.py#L45-L50

```
def __init__(self,
             bigquery_conn_id='bigquery_default',
             delegate_to=None):
    super(BigQueryHook, self).__init__(
        conn_id=bigquery_conn_id,
        delegate_to=delegate_to)
```

Docs for **Airflow 1.9.0**: https://airflow.readthedocs.io/en/1.9.0/integration.html#bigqueryhook

`use_legacy_sql` was added to BigQueryHook init() in **Airflow 1.10.0**.
Docs for **Airflow 1.10.0**: https://airflow.readthedocs.io/en/1.10.0/integration.html#bigqueryhook

Comment: @srikanthramesh can you accept the answer? Also you can use Airflow 1.10 in Composer now (https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/release-notes#october_24_2018_composer-130-airflow-190_composer-130-airflow-1100). You need to enable beta features for this (https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/concepts/beta-support#enable-beta)